# How to modify and manipulate a dataset in R? (new to R user here)

Tags: dataset

I have a dataset already imported into R that has 12 variables but can't seem to find much information about how to filter my dataset by each variable.

For example, one of these variables is "Sex", which has two values, "M" and "F". I'm interested in the sub-datasets that filters down the original dataset with both sexes, to only Males and Females.

Another example is Birth Year: Birth years in the data will range from 1800 to 2007, but I'm interested in birth years that are more recent so (Birth Year > 1990).

What's a simple and easy way to do this? Is it similar to SAS (which is just a few if statements)?

Answer (score 0):

I have recieved the solution to my problem via a professor. Here's the code that helps with this, you need to install the 'dplyer' package in R.

install.packages("dplyr")

library(dplyr)

modified_dataset <- tbl_df(dataset)

Example of "filtering", this one only asks for the Male dataset, instead of the entire dataset

filter(modified_dataset, Sex == 'M')

select(filter(modified_dataset, Sex == 'M'), Name, etc)

only_Male <- modified_dataset %>% filter(Sex == 'M') %>% select(Name, Fed)

This format gets you a new dataset based off of the conditions you ask for.